# moving characters by using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to move matched characters to the end of sentence.

from

```
300p apple in house
orange 200p in school
```

to

```
apple in house 300p
orange in school 200p
```

So I matched `(.+)([\d]+p)(.+)$` and substituted with `\1 \3 \2`.
But the result is like

```
30  apple in house 0p
orange 20  in school 0p
```

I also checked greedy concept, but I don't know what is problem. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(.*?)(\d+p) *(.+)
```

Replace with `\1\3 \2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gz3iux/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string (or line if you use a `m`ultiline mode)
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(\d+p)` - Group 2: one or more digits, and then a `p` char
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `(.+)` - Group 3: any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (since it is a greedy subpattern, no `$` anchor is required, the match will go up to the end of string (or line if you  use a `m`ultiline mode)).

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only, please try following regex.

```
^(\D+)?(\d+p)\s*(.+)$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/rzj5Vb/1)

***Explanation:***

```
^(\D+)?  ##Matching from starting and creating 1st capturing group which has all non-digits in it and keeping it as optional.
(\d+p)   ##Creating 2nd capturing group which matches 1 or more digits followed by p here.
\s*      ##Matching 0 or more occurrences of spaces here.
(.+)$    ##Creating 3rd capturing group here which has everything in it.
```